# Present a default window layout on startup in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, scripting, batch-file

I have a Win7 PC in use as part of an experiment control system. The experiment in question uses 4 windows simultaneously, and I would like to find away to open, position and size these 4 windows with a script.

The script would run at start up, so that the newly booted PC presents the user with the four windows as default.

Obviously I can use a batch file in the startup folder to open windows and run applications, but is there a way to specify the layout of these windows?

Many thanks

Si

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have access to a scripting language that supports making calls to Windows API functions it shouldn't be too hard. Otherwise I'd suggest writing a small executable in some language (at least any of C++, C# or VB.Net would all work fine) and have that do it.

You could use `FindWindow`, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28VS.85%29.aspx), to find the windows and `MoveWindow`, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534%28VS.85%29.aspx), to move them around.

Answer (score 1):

I use an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script to set up all my environment (around 7 windows in 3 different virtual screens), works pretty well. You can set the location of windows etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can use a batch file to open the apps, then run [WiLMA](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-layout-manager/) to relocate them